When we write down the FLRW metric,what are the basis vector or coordiante lines of the coordiante system?
When we consider the coordinate system,it seems we can always ask for how the curvlinear coordinate lines looks like.
So if the universe started evluting from a point,then whether the coordinate system is something like the Fermi coordinate system,whose time axis is the geodesic of the beginner point?
Maybe we can consider a 2 dim universe and 2+1 dim spacetime,so that I can visualize your answer more clearly.
Thanks.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
